# find common ratio in geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please Help Me to answer this question

now im using this formula $$a_n = a_1r^{n-1}$$

now i got a question if the given term is only

$$a_n = 3,960,298,332$$
$$a_1 = 92$$
$$ratio = ??$$
$$n = 16 $$

but i tried $${3960298332 \over 92}$$ $$=43046721$$ 
$$\sqrt[15]{43046721}$$

and the result is $$3.227968874176$$

now is possible to get double in common ratio or its wrong?

. any answer is highly appreciated thank you

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: but i get the r = 3.227968874176

Comment: your result looks correct; if $n$ were $17$, the result would be $3$

Comment: but the given is 16

Comment: @forgeph Your calculations are correct.

Comment: If $n$ is given as $16$, are you sure it's $a_1$ and not $a_0$ that is $92$?

Answer (score -2):

$a_n = a_1r^{n-1}$

$3960298332 = 92 \cdot r ^{n-1}$

$43046721=r^{16-1} \Rightarrow = 43046721=r^{15} $

Take log (base 10) both side,
$7.6339 = 15 \log r \Rightarrow \frac{7.6339}{15}=\log r$

$\log r = 0.5089$

$r = 10^{0.5089} = 3.2277$.(truncated).

Comment: thank you vineet

Comment: @Vineet why take logs both sides when you can take the $15$th root both sides and arrive at the exact solution much easier?

Comment: $7.63/15$ is closer to $0.51$ than to $0.50$

Comment: @peter Definitely we can take 15th root but some basic calculator might lack fractional exponentiation.

Comment: This answer is way off! Using $r=3.16$, we would get $a_{16} \approx 2,909,295,447$, over a billion short of the target. Rounding is dangerous.

Comment: is 3 is the ratio or not?

Comment: Fixed the **truncation issue**. The exponents grow much faster than expected.

Comment: This is still wrong, although you are now closer to the correct value that the OP already found.